# Spacy tokenizer with only "Whitespace" rule

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

I would like to know if the spacy tokenizer could tokenize words only using the "space" rule.
For example:

```
sentence= "(c/o Oxford University )"
```

Normally, using the following configuration of spacy:

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp(sentence)
for token in doc:
   print(token)
```

the result would be:

```
 (
 c
 /
 o
 Oxford
 University
 )
```

Instead, I would like an output like the following (using spacy):

```
(c/o 
Oxford 
University
)
```

Is it possible to obtain a result like this using spacy?

Comment: `sentence.split()`, no SpaCy needed.

Comment: @DYZ unfortunately `sentence.split()` does not provide any NLP info like `nlp(sentence)` do

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's change `nlp.tokenizer` with a custom [`Tokenizer`](https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer#_title) with `token_match` regex:

```
import re
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "This is it's"
print("Before:", [tok for tok in nlp(text)])

nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, token_match=re.compile(r'\S+').match)
print("After :", [tok for tok in nlp(text)])
```

---

```
Before: [This, is, it, 's]
After : [This, is, it's]
```

You can further adjust `Tokenizer` by adding custom suffix, prefix, and infix rules.

An alternative, more fine grained way would be to find out why `it's` token is split like it is with `nlp.tokenizer.explain()`:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
text = "This is it's. I'm fine"
nlp.tokenizer.explain(text)
```

---

You'll find out that split is due to `SPECIAL` rules:

```
[('TOKEN', 'This'),
 ('TOKEN', 'is'),
 ('SPECIAL-1', 'it'),
 ('SPECIAL-2', "'s"),
 ('SUFFIX', '.'),
 ('SPECIAL-1', 'I'),
 ('SPECIAL-2', "'m"),
 ('TOKEN', 'fine')]
```

that could be updated to remove "it's" from exceptions like:

```
exceptions = nlp.Defaults.tokenizer_exceptions
filtered_exceptions = {k:v for k,v in exceptions.items() if k!="it's"}
nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, rules = filtered_exceptions)
[tok for tok in nlp(text)]
```

---

```
[This, is, it's., I, 'm, fine]
```

or remove split on apostrophe altogether:

```
filtered_exceptions = {k:v for k,v in exceptions.items() if "'" not in k}
nlp.tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab, rules = filtered_exceptions)
[tok for tok in nlp(text)]
```

---

```
[This, is, it's., I'm, fine]
```

Note the dot attached to the token, which is due to the suffix rules not specified.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the solution to this very question in the spaCy docs: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#custom-tokenizer-example. In a nutshell, you create a function that takes a string `text` and returns a `Doc` object, and then assign that callable function to `nlp.tokenizer`:

```
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

class WhitespaceTokenizer(object):
    def __init__(self, vocab):
        self.vocab = vocab

    def __call__(self, text):
        words = text.split(' ')
        # All tokens 'own' a subsequent space character in this tokenizer
        spaces = [True] * len(words)
        return Doc(self.vocab, words=words, spaces=spaces)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
nlp.tokenizer = WhitespaceTokenizer(nlp.vocab)
doc = nlp("What's happened to me? he thought. It wasn't a dream.")
print([t.text for t in doc])
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs --

https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#annotations-token
https://spacy.io/api/tokenizer

-- splitting on whitespace is the base behaviour of Tokenizer.

Thus, this simple solution should work:

```
import spacy    
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
tokenizer = Tokenizer(nlp.vocab)
```

There's a minor caveat. You didn't specify what should be done with multiple spaces. SpaCy treats these as separate tokens, so that the exact original text can be recovered from the tokens. `"hello  world"` (with two spaces) will be tokenized as `"hello", " ", "world"`. (With one space, it will of course just be `"hello", "world"`).