# Prevent Spacy tokenizer from splitting on specific character

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, spacy

When using spacy to tokenize a sentence, I want it to not split into tokens on `/`

Example:

```
import en_core_web_lg
nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
for i in nlp("Get 10ct/liter off when using our App"):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
Get
10ct
/
liter
off
when
using
our
App
```

I want it to be like `Get , 10ct/liter, off, when ....`

I was able to find how to add more ways to split into tokens for spacy, but not how to avoid specific splitting techniques.

Comment: Do you just want to [split the text into tokens with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65160277/3832970)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No, I just want it to not split on `/` , everything else is fine. Just splitting on whitespace gives worse quality tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest using a custom tokenizer, see [Modifying existing rule sets](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#native-tokenizer-additions):

```py
import spacy
from spacy.lang.char_classes import ALPHA, ALPHA_LOWER, ALPHA_UPPER, HYPHENS
from spacy.lang.char_classes import CONCAT_QUOTES, LIST_ELLIPSES, LIST_ICONS
from spacy.util import compile_infix_regex

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
text = "Get 10ct/liter off when using our App"
# Modify tokenizer infix patterns
infixes = (
    LIST_ELLIPSES
    + LIST_ICONS
    + [
        r"(?<=[0-9])[+\-\*^](?=[0-9-])",
        r"(?<=[{al}{q}])\.(?=[{au}{q}])".format(
            al=ALPHA_LOWER, au=ALPHA_UPPER, q=CONCAT_QUOTES
        ),
        r"(?<=[{a}]),(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
        r"(?<=[{a}])(?:{h})(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA, h=HYPHENS),
        #r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
        r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
    ]
)

infix_re = compile_infix_regex(infixes)
nlp.tokenizer.infix_finditer = infix_re.finditer
doc = nlp(text)
print([t.text for t in doc])
## =>  ['Get', '10ct/liter', 'off', 'when', 'using', 'our', 'App']
```

Note the commented `#r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=/](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),` line, I simply took out the `/` char from the `[:<>=/]` character class. This rule split at `/` that is between a letter/digit and a letter.

If you need to still split `'12/ct'` into three tokens, you will need to add another line below the `r"(?<=[{a}0-9])[:<>=](?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA)` line:

```
r"(?<=[0-9])/(?=[{a}])".format(a=ALPHA),
```

Comment: Note that I am using Spacy 3.0.1, and thus have used `en_core_web_trf` model. You can still use your `en_core_web_lg` one.

Comment: Worked very well, thanks for the explanation Wiktor!